# Difference between JodaTime and Calendar for years before 1900

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, jodatime

I'm getting different values in milliseconds for the same date in past while using JodaTime lib and java.util.Calendar.
For example for the first year AD

```
void test() {
    int year = 1;
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, 1,1,0,0,0,0);
    dt = dt.toDateTime(GregorianChronology.getInstance());

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    DateTime endDate = new DateTime(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    endDate = endDate.toDateTime(GregorianChronology.getInstance());

    System.out.println("JodaTime: " + dt);
    System.out.println("JodaTime, ms: " + dt.getMillis());
    System.out.println("Calendar: " + cal.getTime());
    System.out.println("Calendar, ms: " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("JodaTime by Calendar: " + endDate);
}
```

By default DateTime use ISOChronology and Calendar is GregorianCalendar (except TH and JA locales). So I set GregorianChronology, but nothing changed.
Result of execution is

```
JodaTime:       0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:34:52
JodaTime, ms:   -62135602492000
Calendar:       Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 EET 1
Calendar, ms:   -62135776800000
JodaTime by Calendar:   0000-12-29T23:34:52.000+01:34:52
```

Could someone suggest am I wrong with something?

Comment: Using `GregorianCalendar` for dates before 1582 is rather suspect overall...

Comment: According to GregorianCalendar javadoc it "implements proleptic Gregorian and Julian calendars. That is, dates are computed by extrapolating the current rules indefinitely far backward and forward in time. As a result, GregorianCalendar may be used for all years to generate meaningful and consistent results. However, dates obtained using GregorianCalendar are historically accurate only from March 1, 4 AD onward, when modern Julian calendar rules were adopted." But It's the answer, I think. The problem is in dates before 1582.

Comment: It is worth noting that while the Gregorian calendar was introduced in 1582, it wasn't used officially in many countries until much later. Some less than 100 years ago.  In the USA it was adopted retrospectively when they gained independence.  George Washington, changed his year, month and day of birth as a result during his life. In the British Calendar Act of 1751 declared that the day after Sep 2, 1752 would be Sep 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some tests I've found out next things:

1. The problem is my code is that it uses Europe/Athens time zone. Atm it has offset 2 hrs and until 1916 it used to be equal 1:34:52 (thanx Jon Skeet for help). But only Joda Time knows about it =). That's why I had difference since 1582 till 1916 years (not 1900 as I supposed before)
   So since 1582-10-15 both Sun's Calendar and Joda Time acts similar (if you use UTC time zone)
2. But if you try to create 1582-10-14 using java.util.Calendar (cal.set(1582, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0);) you'll get Sun Oct 24 00:00:00 EET 1582 (and right date in Joda Time). The same true for 05-14.10.1582. Before 1582-10-05 you'll get right string representation for Calendar, but different milliseconds value. And the difference becoming less by some rule. That's why in my example it was 3 days lag. As far as I remember it's connected with Julian calendar

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 4):

My *guess* is that it's to do with your time zone. Specify UTC to remove that from the equation.

Some time zones (e.g. Paris) have had some "interesting" transitions.

For example, zoneinfo suggests that Europe/Athens had an offset of 1:34:52 until 1916 (switching from an abbreviation of LMT to AMT in 1895).

Belarus had an offset of 1:50:16 until 1880.

Perhaps Java is using a different source of time zone data which doesn't include these oddities?

Comment: Your guess is good.  Time was not consistent in 1 AD.  This appears to me as Joda being smarter than Calendar.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I've checked that instances of DateTime and Calenar has the same time zones but didn't try to change them (I've just printed TimeZones). I'll try UTC, thanks Jon.

Comment: @Erick: our calendar not being consistently applicable to dates before its inception means that there really is no smart way to do it. And the Sun/Oracle JRE and Joda Time both use the tz database. They may be using different versions, though.

Comment: I've tried UTC and it clarified everything since 1582 - Calendar and DateTime are the same, and 25 minutes difference was because of offsets. But looks like before 1582 Sun Calendar and Joda Time implemented differently (I suppose the reason is leap years 1200, 800 and 400)